# Error creating new object from admin - Django 1.7.5

Tags: django, django-admin

When I'm trying to create a new entry from admin interface (/admin)  I'm getting:

> required_label_tag() got an unexpected keyword argument 'label_suffix'
>
> Exception Location:    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\helpers.py in label_tag, line 131

---

> Error during template rendering
>
> In template C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\includes\fieldset.html, error at line 15

Line 15:

> {{ field.label_tag }}

---

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\helpers.py" in label_tag
>     131.                                     label_suffix='' if self.is_checkbox else None)

My project was starting from django 1.5 and then migrate to 1.7.5

any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: I can fix this editing helpers.py deleting:

> label_suffix='' if self.is_checkbox else None

but I think this isn't the way...

Comment: We can't possibly help you without seeing the code or the traceback.

Comment: The code is a default admin register =( 
what code do you need? I edited the post with more details

Comment: Are you rendering a custom form in the admin? If so check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.label_tag